# Regex Match Ampersand but not escaped xml characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to match ampersand (&) but not when it exists in following manner

```
&apos;
&quot;
&gt;
&lt;
&amp;
&#
```

So in the following line
    `& MY& NAME IS M&Hh. &apos; &quot; &gt; &lt; &amp; &# &&&&&&`

I want it to match all ampersands except those which exist in 
    `&apos; &quot; &gt; &lt; &amp; &#`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That looks like a job for [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)
```

should work.

**Explanation:**

```
&        # Match &
(?!      # only if it's not followed by
 (?:     # either
  apos   # apos
 |quot   # or quot
 |[gl]t  # or gt/lt
 |amp    # or amp
 );      # and a semicolon
|        # or
 \#      # a hash
)        # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: Nice regex, Tim. I'm still in love with this tool, so pardon me while I [link a fancier diagram](http://www.regexper.com/#%26(%3F!(%3F%3Aapos%7Cquot%7C%5Bgl%5Dt%7Camp)%3B%7C%23)).

Comment: I wish I had more than one vote.  This was a very helpful answer!  Exactly what I was looking for.