# How do I escape characters using the Node xml2js module?

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-parsing, xml2js

I have an xml document with an & in it, so I am getting an error

```
   [Error: Invalid character in entity name
   Line: 155
   Column: 63
   Char:  ]
```

I wrote a function to escape illegal xml characters:

```
const escapeIllegalCharacters = (xml) => {
  xml = xml 
    .replace(/&/g,'&amp;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
    .replace(/'/g, '&apos;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;');
  return (xml);
}
```

And put it into a valueProcessor:

```
return parse.parseString(xml, {valueProcessors: [escapeIllegalCharacters]});
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Is this the wrong way to escape characters using the xml2js module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersands before calling `parseString`.

You can use the regular expression from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423126/6680611) to escape ampersands that themselves are not part of an espace sequence:

```js
return parse.parseString(
  xml.replace(/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/g, '&amp;')
);
```

Whether or not this will solve your problem will depend upon the content of your XML. For example, this simplistic mechanism will also escape any ampersands in `CDATA` sections, but ampersands in those sections should be left unescaped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I actually tried to run my escape function before calling parseString, but then I ran into the problem you mentioned where I was escaping the opening and closing tags of the xml characters themselves. I think your above solution would work for ampersands but is there a general solution for escaping all illegal characters only between tags? I thought the valueProcessors solution would be it...

Comment: The bottom line is that your XML is invalid and that parser is not going to accept it. Perhaps there is another that is more forgiving? If you have unescaped `<` and `>` characters in there, too, you have a real problem. Any parser would need way of determining whether or not something is a tag, etc. So there would always be ambiguities and no general solution.

Comment: Yeah fair point, I checked your answer and it works for ampersands, I'm going to mark it correct. Thanks!