# Parsing XML file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I am using an Arch Linux system with KDE plasma. I have approximately 50mb XML, and I need to parse it. The file has custom tags.

Example XML:

```xml
<JMdict>
   <entry>
      <ent_seq>1000000</ent_seq>
      <r_ele>
         <reb>ヽ</reb>
      </r_ele>
      <sense>
         <pos>&unc;</pos>
         <gloss g_type="expl">repetition mark in katakana</gloss>
      </sense>
   </entry>
</JMdict>
```

I have tried many solutions that were suggested on Stack Overflow, and they did not work at all, and some of them could not installed to my system like `xml-stream`, `xml2json`. I decided to use `xml2js` (most of them suggest to use `xml2js`), and got the same result. How can I correctly use it ?
I am using this code but it always returns undefined:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

const path = "test.xml";

fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(error, data) {
     parser.parseString(data, function(err, res) {
         console.log(res);
     });
});

Result: Undefined
```

Is there any way to handle an XML file by hand (without a package)?

Comment: Your "XML" file is not well-formed: it contains an undefined entity reference `&unc;`.  So parsing *should* fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is below [Working Example Link](https://repl.it/repls/PlumpHollowComputing)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
slash = require('slash'),
xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

let filename = slash(__dirname+'/foo.xml');

// console.log(filename);

fs.readFile(filename,  "utf8", function(err, data) {

    if(err) {
        console.log('Err1111');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //console.log(data);
        // data.toString('ascii', 0, data.length)

        parser.parseString(data.replace(/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/g, '&amp;'), function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Err');
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log('Done');
            }            
        });
    }
});
```

Exact you have to do it below :

> data.replace(/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/g, '&')

Problem is  below tag only **&unc;**

```
<pos>&unc;</pos>
```

[Referenced And Thanks to @tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423126/8300249)

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is unescaped characters in your xml data.

I'm able to get your example to work by using this:

xml data:

```
<JMdict>
    <entry>
        <ent_seq>1000000</ent_seq>
        <r_ele>
            <reb>ヽ</reb>
        </r_ele>
        <sense>
             <pos>YOUR PROBLEM WAS HERE</pos>
             <gloss g_type="expl">repetition mark in katakana</gloss>
        </sense>
    </entry>
```

node.js code:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

const path = "test.xml";

fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(error, data) {
     parser.parseString(data, function(err, res) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res.JMdict.entry, null, 4));
     });

});
```

In situations like this, when I know it should work fine, I always look at the data and for any possible issues with the input data.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use the xml2js package should be fine. However, the format of your xml is a little bit off.

if you add a `console.log` to see what's causing the error

```
fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(error, data) {
     parser.parseString(data, function(err, res) {
         if (err) console.log(err);

         console.log(res);
     });
});
```

You'll see that it's the line `<pos>&unc;</pos>` that causes the problem.
If you fix the HTML entities, the parser should works fine.